# "Making music" and "music making" as a noun

Tags: nouns, gerunds, noun-phrases

I have always been wondering if one of these forms is more correct in formal writing: The verb-ing + noun form and the noun + verb-ing form.

For example:

- Making music is a skill anyone can learn.
- Music making is a skill anyone can learn.

Or:

- Hunting whales should be banned in our country.
- Whale hunting should be banned in our country.

They seem to have slightly different meanings to me, but I can't quite put my finger on it. Is there a preference for one over the other in certain situations?

Comment: Meaningwise, they seem the same to me, but syntactically different, of course. Btw, "music-making" and "whale-hunting" are compound nouns so probably best hyphenated.

Answer (score 1):

Constructions with the gerund are sometimes noun-like and sometimes verb-like (and sometimes the distinction is blurred).

The first of each of your pairs is verb-like, whereas the second is noun-like. One indicator of this is that the dependent goes in front of the gerund in a noun-like construction but after it in a verb-like one - which obviously is the difference you've noticed.

In each case the main verb wants a noun phrase as its subject, so the second is preferable - but I'm sure you would find examples of the first.

In a formal context the first version of each would be turned into a proper noun phrase by saying something like *the hunting of whales*. For example, the (UK) Hunting Act 2004  provides *the hunting of rabbits is exempt if...*.

Answer (score 0):

Saying it as **music-making** sets the gerund in the sentence primarily as a noun, as in "His compositions were influenced by the great tradition of music-making in that country." (Cambridge Dictionary of English).

But saying it as **making music** (without a hyphen) emphasizes the verb aspect, as in "Making music at home has never been cheaper.", or your example: "Making music is a skill anyone can learn."

Similarly, since in your whale hunting example the emphasis is the noun, "Whale hunting should be banned in our country" is more appropriate.